# How to change language in genymotion simulator by shell command

Tags: shell, genymotion

I've a question, does anyone know how to change genymotion language using shell script?

I need this to run simulator with desired language before my calabash tests will run.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 2):

Found a solution with changing a language, by adb command:

adb shell "setprop persist.sys.language es; setprop persist.sys.country US; setprop ctl.restart zygote"